# Dividend reinvestment into shares query

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I'm gonna get straight to the problem:

Image dividend reinvestment as this scenario:

- You buy **10 shares of AAPL on `2018-01-01` for $10**
- -- AAPL pays **$1 / per share** dividend on `2018-02-01` -> you get **$10 CASH**

  - This **CASH** is automatically reinvested into shares: **1 AAPL share costs $20 on `2018-02-01`** -> `shares_per_dividend = $1 (dividend amount) / 20 (AAPL price_per_share) = 0.05` -> you get + `0.5 shares` calculated as: `10 (cash from dividends) * 0.05 (shares_per_dividend)`
  - Now you have `10 (initial shares) + 0.5 (new shares)` = **`10.5` shares**
- -- AAPL pays **$1 / per share** dividend on `2018-03-01 (month after first dividend)` -> *now* you get **$10.5 cash** as you have **10.5** shares of AAPL

  - For the sake of simplicity **AAPL again costs $20** on `2018-03-01` so you automatically buy `10.5 * shares_per_dividend (0.05) = 0.525 new shares` -> now you have `10.5 + 0.525` = **11.025** shares

This could go on and on... The point is, after every paid dividend I want to **add "CASH-BOUGHT" shares to initial shares**, and then on next dividend date I want to **multiply `shares_per_dividend` by current amount of owned shares** (eg. **10.5** mentioned above)

Hope I expressed myself right :)

---

I would write query similar to this using window function, but it does not take current shares in account.

```sql
SELECT shares + shares * SUM(shares_per_dividend) OVER(PARTITION BY stock_symbol ORDER BY dividend_date ASC) as current_shares
FROM some_table;
```

`shares_per_dividend` is `NULL` if no dividend was paid on that day.

example of calculations:
[image: example of correct calculations]

the final result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: `10 + 10x0.05` is `10x(1+0.05)` and `10.5 + 10.5x0.05` is `10.5x(1+0.05)` with is then also `10x(1+0.05)x(1+0.05)` since your `10.5` came as result of computation of previous step, and then all later steps are derived in the same way... so `10x(1.05)^3`, `10x(1.05)^4`, etc.

Comment: Patrik Mevzek - thanks for suggestion but shares_per_dividend could be any other value each time dividend is paid. It depends on closing price of that company on that very day.

Comment: You will get more / better answers if you post your CREATE TABLE statement and some input data so people can experiment with your problem easier.